# Why is my regex not finding any matches?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I have a ***string*** that looks like this with the spaces and everything.

```
            id: 123456789,
            name: 'HappyDev',
            member: false,
            language: 0,
            isLoggedIn: 0
```

And here is my pattern

```
static string pattern = @"              id: (.*),
                name: (.*),
                member: (.*),
                language: (.*),
                isLoggedIn: (.*)";
```

Then to get my match I do it like so..

```
static Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(myString);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
                }
```

For some reason it's returning false when I compile even though on every website where I can test my pattern it returns a match with the values.
Why is it returning false when I compile?

Comment: a guess: you have the singleline option set, but the string contains multiple lines?

Comment: @dlatikay: That's not what `SingleLine` means.  That's about wildcards.

Comment: Ive tried with and without, no go.

Comment: My guess would be a mismatch between file line break and code line breaks. Could you try to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Also your string has 12 spaces for prefix and your pattern has 14. And subsequent lines in your pattern have 16 spaces.

Comment: I count 14 spaces in the string, and only 12 in the pattern. maybe due to the SO code formatting or lost in copy/paste, but check it.

Comment: @Heinzi https://regex101.com/r/OTmi0L/3

Comment: @AleksSlade: I meant an mvce of your C# code: The source of a complete, minimal Console project .cs file that we can copy/paste into Visual Studio and tweak until it works.

Comment: @Heinzi Coming right up

Comment: why not use `(?:: ?)(.*)(?:,)|(?:: ?)(.*)` as pattern ... thats a non-capturing `:` followed maybe by whitespace and then capturing till linend except optional `,` withspecial handling oflast line without `,`

Comment: I was going to make a similar suggestion as @PatrickArtner - it's *much* easier to read. No one will like having to count the number of spaces in your current regex.

Comment: a little bit of context and purpuse would be nice, are the number of space mandatory? Are those Attibute mandatory? Is the order mandatory? May one be missing or may there be others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have different number of spaces. To ignore this problem in any case you can use a pattern to match multiple spaces: `\s+`. Also you should replace your new lines with a pattern for new line: `[\n\r]+` (note that this will match any number of new lines)

So your pattern becomes:

```
static string pattern = @"\s+id: (.*),[\n\r]+\s+name: (.*),[\n\r]+\s+member: (.*),[\n\r]+\s+language: (.*),[\n\r]+\s+isLoggedIn: (.*)";
```

Comment: This will not work if the space between `:` and the value is missing or different (e.g. more than one space). It's generally considered good practice to account for/ignore white space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

Pattern

```
(?:: ?)(.*)(?:,)|(?:: ?)(.*)
```

Explanation:

```
1st Alternative (?:: ?)(.*)(?:,)
Non-capturing group (?:: ?)
  : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
     ? matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
  ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times 
    as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  1st Capturing Group (.*)
  .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
  * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many 
    times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  Non-capturing group (?:,)
    , matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

2nd Alternative (?:: ?)(.*)
Non-capturing group (?:: ?)
  : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
     ? matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
  ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times 
    as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  2nd Capturing Group (.*)
  .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
  * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many 
    times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

You loose the distinctness of specifying ID etc - but you reley on non-named capturing groups with implicit ordering anyways - so some place for refinement. If you think they might skip params or reorder them, I would keep the named identifiers part of the pattern and add names to the capturing groups so they are decoupled from ordering.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of solving this. Here is mine:

```
string pattern = @"^id:\s*(.+),[\n|\r|\r\n]\s+name:(.+),[\n|\r|\r\n]\s+member:\s+(.+),[\n|\r|\r\n]\s+language:\s+(.+),[\n|\r|\r\n]\s+isLoggedIn:\s+(.+)$";
```

It will account for any space in-between as well as any combination of carriage return/line feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = @"
    id: 123456789,
    name: 'HappyDev',
    member: false,
    language: 0,
    isLoggedIn: 0";

var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?im)(?'attr'\w+):\s+(?'val'[^,]+)");
if (matches.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No matches found");
else
    matches.Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(m =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Match: '{m.Value}' [Attribute = {m.Groups["attr"].Value}, Value = {m.Groups["val"].Value}]"));
```

Comment: In addition to that if you have a set of attribute that are valid you can store them in a array. And a simple contains will be enought.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Regex101, your pattern have spacing issues (number of spaces don't match).

You can use the following regex for spaces and new line chars so no more need to worry for how many spaces:

```
id: (.*),\s*name: (.*),\s*member: (.*),\s*language: (.*),\s*isLoggedIn: (.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the initial code, check if the amount of spaces is equal in the string and pattern. This code finds the match:

```
var myString = 
@"            id: 123456789,
            name: 'HappyDev',
            member: false,
            language: 0,
            isLoggedIn: 0";
string pattern = 
@"            id:.*,
            name: (.*),
            member: (.*),
            language: (.*),
            isLoggedIn: (.*)";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(myString);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

However, you shouldn't use it like that, but replace spaces with ( +) or make use of other solutions provided here.